# enumerative combinatorics,In how many ways (as a function of n) can one choose a composition α α of n

Tags: combinatorics

Fix $n\in P$. In how many ways (as a function of n) can one choose a composition $\alpha$ of n, and then choose a composition of each part of $\alpha$?

Comment: Presumably P is non-standard notation for the set of positive integers. But what is a "composition"?

Comment: @almagest: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29).

Answer (score 4):

The end result of the process is a composition $\beta$ of $n$. Suppose that $\beta$ has $k$ parts. There are $2^{k-1}$ ways to group these parts into blocks of consecutive parts: doing so is essentially just forming a composition of $k$. Replace each block by its sum, and you get a partition $\alpha$ of $n$ from which you can produce $\beta$ by replacing each part of $\alpha$ by a composition of that part.

There are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts, and each of them can be produced from $2^{k-1}$ different partitions $\alpha$ of $n$. Thus, the answer to the question is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}2^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}k2^k\;,$$

which I’ll leave to you to evaluate in closed form.

Comment: +1 Neat. And I have learnt a term for a kind of ordered partition. Thanks.

Comment: @almagest: You’re welcome.